# How to incorporate babel with my regular AngularJs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, babeljs

In my angular app, my index.html looks like

```
<head>
  <script src="app/app.js></script
  <script src="app/controllers/controller1.js></script
  <script src="app/services/service1.js></script>
   ...
   ...
</head>
```

where each js file has the following structure

```
//controller1.js
(function() {
  angular.module('controller1', function() ....

})()
```

In development mode
My express server simply serves the index.html which then loads each file indiviually in the browser.

For production of.. I concatenate all files and there is a entire build process using gulp.

My question is..how do I start using ES6 features in my file in development ?
I am aware that I am suppose to transpiler using Babel.
However in development, how do I ask the browser to transpile using babel ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have babel watch your dev directory for changes, and re-transpile every time you save. (See https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/)

`$ babel script.js --watch --out-file script-compiled.js`

Include the transpiled files (not the source files) in your HTML document, and on every refresh, you see the latest.